# How to create and insert a JSON object using MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql, json, nosql, sql-update, sql-insert

I'm trying to create a JSON object and then read the values from it into MySQL table. But I'm facing errors and I'm new to both JSON and MySQL.

```
SET @j = '{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}';
CREATE TABLE Person (name int,id int);
INSERT INTO Person (name,id) SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@j) WITH (name int,id int);
```

Comment: OPENJSON is used in sqlserver (T-SQL), you tagged your question mysql. Wich are you using ?

Comment: i m using mysql 5.6 or ms sql server 2008 @JeanDoux

Answer (score 61, accepted):

On creating table set your field as **JSON** datatype.

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `name` json DEFAULT NULL
);
```

And Insert JSON data into it,

```
INSERT INTO `person` (`name`)
VALUES ('["name1", "name2", "name3"]');
```

Or Insert JSON data by *Key:Value*

```
INSERT INTO person VALUES ('{"pid": 101, "name": "name1"}');
INSERT INTO person VALUES ('{"pid": 102, "name": "name2"}');
```

Select JSON data,

```
SELECT * FROM `person` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(name, '["name1"]');
```

Note: *Only supported by MySQL 5.7 (or higher) using InnoDB.*

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'json DEFAULT NULL, )' at line 2" this is the error i am encountering

Comment: MySQL 5.7 InnoDB or higher versions only supports.