# SQL Insert JSON into table column

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, sql-insert

While searching for a way to insert array into single DB columns, I found an article about inserting JSON strings. However it wasn't explained how. I tried to search and find the way with no success.

I have the following table:

| Name | Type |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | int | AI |
| name | String |  |
| address | JSON(longtext) |  |

What I want to do is insert a JSON array in the `address` column, like:

| id | name | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User name | `[{street: "street address", city: "Berlin"}]` |

I thought about inserting the JSON as String but I'm not sure if this a good idea. Any suggestions?

Comment: No don't convert the json to string. You already have json datatype in MySQL from 5.7 version. Insert the column directly. It accepts.

Comment: The JSON you show is not valid JSON. You need to delimit keys with double-quotes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can pass your data as a string, as long as it is valid JSON; MySQL will happily convert it for you under the hood.

```
insert into mytable (id, name, address)
values (
    1,
    'User name',
    '[{"street": "street address", "city": "Berlin"}]'
);
```

An alternative is to use JSON builder functions:

```
insert into mytable (id, name, address)
values (
    1,
    'User name',
    json_array(json_object('street', 'street address', 'city', 'Berlin'))
);
```

Answer (score 2):

This works in my case. In summary use `ARRAY[CAST('{"key": "val"}' as json)]`.

Example:

```
insert into <table_name> (id, name, address)
values ('1', 
        'User name', 
         array[cast('{"street": "street address", "city": "Berlin"}' as json)])
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE people (id INT, name VARCHAR(255), address JSON);
>
> INSERT INTO people (id, name, address)
> VALUES (1, 'User name', '[{"street": "street address", "city": "Berlin"}]');
>
> SELECT *
> FROM people;
> ```

| id | name | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User name | [{"city": "Berlin", "street": "street address"}] |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3a0954a9e3fd293d035990856f3a83ec)*

Comment: Thank you for your replay. much appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

@GMB's alternative answer looks correct but I thought I would add another answer to show how I implemented this in a format that I prefer:

```
INSERT INTO <table name>  
SET field1 = '123',
    field2 = json_array(‘456’);
```

I like listing my field names next to their values so I don't have to mentally map the values to the variables.

Also, I didn't need the json_object since I was not entering a key:value pair - I was just entering a list of values.

Comment: Tbh. This is the answer I was looking for :). The other answer is also good and working.

Answer (score 0):

Why converting to String if you already have a datatype JSON in MySQL

```
INSERT INTO <Table_Name> VALUES ('{street: "street address", city: "Berlin"}');
```

This insert statement will directly inserts your array. There is no need to convert.

See this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40930896/how-to-create-and-insert-a-json-object-using-mysql-queries)

Comment: Thank you man. i appreciate your replay and expain